# Pytorch Neural Network Errors

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to compute the loss and accuracy of a certain  machine learning model by using Pytorch and I am having trouble initializing the dataset so that it can run. Using the Moon dataset, I am getting a few errors when I run the code. I first initialize the dataset:

```
X, y = make_moons(200, noise=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1, stratify = y)
x, y = Variable (torch.from_numpy(X_train)).float(), Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train)).float()
```

and then when I run the Neural Network:

```
    def __init__(self):
        super(SoftmaxRegression, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(200, 1)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
```

I get the following errors:
serWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument. 
x = F.softmax(self.layer(x)) 
ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight,  _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index) 
IndexError: Target 1 is out of bounds.

How can I fix this so that it can run the dataset and output the loss and accuracy?

Comment: Can you provide full traceback?

Comment: @null This is the code that I have developed thus far

`X, y = sklearn.datasets.make_moons(200, noise=0.20)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1, stratify = y)
def __init__(self):
        super(SoftmaxRegression, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(500, 1)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
`
everytime I try running it it states that the arguments need to be at least 1D, but they are 0D and 2D.

Comment: @null So I tried converting them to tensors and it still does not work. I am trying to print out the loss and accuracy of the neural network by running on that dataset.

Comment: I meant the full "error" traceback. can you put it in the answer ?

Comment: @null I edited the question again, but here are the errors I am getting:
errors: serWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument. x = F.softmax(self.layer(x))
ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index) IndexError: Target 1 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry to put this as an answer but unfortunately stack overflow won't let me comment :/).

Even if the Softmax worked it is absolutely pointless.(Unless you are softmaxing across your batch but that would be really weird). Your code shows you have a linear layer going from a tensor of 200 to 1. Softmax on a single value will simply return that value, Softmaxing should only be used on 2 or more values.

If you wish to do binary classification I would instead change the code to be this:

```
    import torch.nn.functional as F

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = F.sigmoid(x)
        return x
```

Comment: @user13382352 So what shoudl I be running instead of softmax? I tried logistic regression and the program was resolving at around 50% accuracy.

Comment: You should instead use `self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()` so your code would become `x = self.fc(x)` followed by `x=self.sig(x)`. That is if you're doing binary classification

Comment: So the code for the class would become this?
`
class Sigmoid(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sigmoid, self).__init__()
        self.fc(x)
        x = self.sig(x)
`

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how I'd change the code you can remove the line for creating the softmax in __init__(). By the way do you know what super does?

Comment: So when I ran this code: 
`class Sigmoid(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sigmoid, self).__init__()
        self.fc(x)
        #x = self.sig(x)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = F.sigmoid(x)
        return x
` I got this new error message: 
raise ModuleAttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(  
torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'Sigmoid' object has no attribute 'fc'

Comment: you forgot to write self.fc = nn.Linear(200,1). I don't mean to be rude at all but have you done much programming before?

Comment: I have done a little, but I am trying to learn :/. hence the name.

Comment: So when I run the class code: 
`class Sigmoid(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sigmoid, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(200, 1)
        self.fc(x)
` I get the error that x is not defined.

Comment: No worries. Have you covered objects before? cause if not, it would really help to do so. (I think code academy has some good stuff for that if you can skip ahead). Also if you just wanna throw together a neural net that can do something I would recommend using tensorflow and keras instead. For creating a simple model it's a lot easier to do. (however when things start getting more advanced it does get trickier, so if you're REALLY into neural nets then it may be worth sticking out the pytorch learning curve). But before you continue on with pytorch it's really worth learning objects first.

Comment: btw could you paste bin your stuff it would be a lot easier to read